# How to identify the full command that caused the crash from the core dump file

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb, coredump

There is a problem to identify the full command from the core dump file using gdb
The crashed  command itself can be long

i.e.

```
myCommand -f log/SlaRunTimeReport.rep -I input/myFile.txt -t output/myFile.txt
```

But When using gdb to identify the command in the location “Core was generated by”

i.e. by executing

```
gdb -c core.56536
```

The Output:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.10-20.el7

….

Core was generated by `myCommand -f log/SlaRunTimeReport.rep -I 
input/myFile.t'.
```

It is possible to see that the full command(executable + parameters)  was cut in the middle

```
‘myCommand -f log/SlaRunTimeReport.rep -I input/myFile.t'
```

In additional using **strings** command , also did not help to identify the full command

```
strings core.56536 | grep PMRunTimeReport
```

The Output:

```
myCommand 

myCommand -f log/SlaRunTimeReport.rep -I input/myFile.t
```

Is there any way to get from coredump file the full command that caused the failure

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can't you just print the contents of `argv` in the stack frame containing `main()`?

Comment: Please try to format the question correctly.

Comment: I would provide very short file names to circumvent length limitations in the output. If only long parameters causing troubles consider this a hint into your bug.

Comment: This could be a symptom of a storage overlay, that overlaid part of argv's list.... to prove, print out the contents of the argv argument list at the start of the program... then when it dumps, check to see if GDB shows the same value as was printed at the start of the program.... if not, then you know a storage overlay occurred.  Hopefully, you've used valgrind.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any way to get from coredump file the full command that caused the failure

There are multiple ways, but running `strings` is the *wrong* way.

IF you built your program with debug info, you should be able to simply execute `up` command until you reach `main`, then examine `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]`.

If your `main` was not built with debug info, or if it doesn't use `argc` and `argv`, you should be able to recover that info from `__libc_argc` and `__libc_argv` variables. Example:

```
$ ./a.out foo bar baz $(python -c 'print "a" * 500')
Aborted (core dumped)

$ gdb -q ./a.out core
Core was generated by `./a.out foo bar baz aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'.
```

Note that the "generated by" is truncated -- it comes from a fixed length array inside of `struct prpsinfo`, saved in `NT_PRPSINFO` ELF note in the `core`.

```
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007fab38cfcf2b in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.27-15.fc28.x86_64

(gdb) p (int)__libc_argc
$1 = 5
(gdb) p ((char**)__libc_argv)[0]@5
$2 = {0x7ffede43289f "./a.out", 0x7ffede4328a7 "foo", 0x7ffede4328ab "bar",
  0x7ffede4328af "baz", 
  0x7ffede4328b3 'a' <repeats 200 times>...}
```

This last line is actually a lie -- we know that `'a'` repeats 500 times.

We can fix it like so:

```
(gdb) set print elem 0
(gdb) p ((char**)__libc_argv)[0]@5
$3 = {0x7ffede43289f "./a.out", 0x7ffede4328a7 "foo", 0x7ffede4328ab "bar",
  0x7ffede4328af "baz", 
  0x7ffede4328b3 'a' <repeats 500 times>}
```

Voila: we now have the complete command.

Lastly, if you install debug info for GLIBC, you can simply look in the `__libc_start_main` (which called your `main`):

```
(gdb) set backtrace past-main
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007fab38ce7561 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00000000004004ef in main () at foo.c:3
#3  0x00007fab38ce918b in __libc_start_main (main=0x4004e6 <main>, argc=5, argv=0x7ffede431118, 
    init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffede431108)
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#4  0x000000000040042a in _start ()
```

Here you can clearly see `argc` and `argv` in frame 3, and can examine *that* `argv` like so:

```
(gdb) fr 3
#3  0x00007fab38ce918b in __libc_start_main (main=0x4004e6 <main>, argc=5, argv=0x7ffede431118, 
    init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffede431108)
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
308       result = main (argc, argv, __environ MAIN_AUXVEC_PARAM);

(gdb) p argv[0]@5
$1 = {0x7ffede43289f "./a.out", 0x7ffede4328a7 "foo", 0x7ffede4328ab "bar",
  0x7ffede4328af "baz", 
  0x7ffede4328b3 'a' <repeats 500 times>}
```

Comment: I had tried to run :   gdb -q ./myCommand -c core.56590   , Then  : **p (int)__libc_argc**   result is:   **$1 = 7**                                       Then run the next:  **set print elem 0**                                            and then :  p ((char**)__libc_argv)[0]@7                                                                                   No success  , got : Cannot access memory at address 0x3003ff68

Comment: I also tried the the other suggestion , But I assume I have no debug info for glibc , I run : 
 **set backtrace past-main** 

, then I run: 
 **bt**  

then I looked for  __libc_start_main  and run in my case : 

**fr 2** 

, but there is no argc in the output that I got :
 **#2  0x00007fbda6d46b35 in __libc_start_main () ** 
from /lib64/libc.so.6** 

, then I run : 

**p argc **

and  got : 

**No symbol "argc" in current context.**

Comment: @AlexOstar "I have no debug info for glibc" is a solvable problem: install it.